# Different output script generated by linq to sql 2016 Express/Standard edition vs developer edition

Tags: linq, execution

I'm developing desktop application (WinForm) using vb.net and using LINQ to access the database (SQLSERVER 2016)

I have 2 instance database identical DB(same structure and data).
- SQLEXPRESS2016 (Express edition)
- SQLSERVER2016 (Developer edition)

But why I getting significant Different time execution and different schema execution plan also? The sql script generated by LINQ??

```
dim myResult = (from i in myDataContext.ItemMaster _
                Where i.IsActive _
                Order by m.ItemNumber).AsQueryable

dim count = myResult.Count()
```

I profiling the query generated by linq by SQL Server profiling, and myResult.Count()  will generated the script (in this case the script is same between dev and standard/express):

```
 Select Count(1) AS [value]
FROM( Select TOP (1000) NULL AS [EMPTY]
      FROM ITEM_MASTER as [t0] WHERE IS_Active = 1
      ORDER BY [t0].[ItemNumber]
)AS [t1]
```

My Question are:
1. Why in some cases the query was different between
Express/Standard edition and Developer edition? (The DB structure and data is same, just different version)
one will generated SELECT TOP (1)..., the other will SELECT TOP (2) ....

2. Why The execution time different is significant.
   dev = 0.xx seconds
   std/express = 8s econds.
   it should not a big deal, since the number of rows about 10,000 something
3. Why the execution plan also different? std/express seems more complicated schema and some index is missing.

[screenshot sql dev vs express/standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xZkX.png)

Answer (score 0):

It solved by adding NOEXPAND hint keyword.
See original answer here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b095ce80-6b19-45a5-9a31-4532fcd8af83/different-output-script-generated-by-linq-to-sql-2016-expressstandard-edition-vs-developer-edition?forum=sqlnetfx

credit to: Yuvraj Singh Bais